# Find the $100p^{th}$ percentile

Tags: probability

The question is:

Suppose the random variable X has pdf

$f(x) = \begin{cases} {e^{-t}}&x\geq 0 \\ 0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$

Find the $100p^{th}$ percentile.

So I did

$F(x)$ = $\int_0^xe^{-t}dt$ so I end up getting $1-e^{-x}$. From here I thought I just set it equal to 100 and solve for x, but I end up getting $-\ln(-99)$ which is not a real number. What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: $100\%$ is the same as $1$.

Comment: If I set it equal to 1, I just get 0 though. What would I do with that? @FabioSomenzi

Comment: Simplifying, you get $e^{-x} = 0$, which is only true in the limit.  If your random variable has that pdf, in order to include everybody/everything, you need to go to infinity.

Comment: What am I going to infinity at? Make my integral 0 to infinity instead of 0 to x? @FabioSomenzi

Comment: I suspect the question is really about a generic percentile, which is often written $(100p)^{th}$ percentile.  Therefore your equation is $\int_0^x e^{-t} dt = p$.  If $p$ is $1$, then $x \to \infty$, but for $0 \leq p < \infty$, you get a value of $x$ by solving $e^{-x} = 1-p$, which I'm sure you know you solve by taking logarithms.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi, Okay, this makes sense but I honestly don't know what p is. The only similar example I have in my notes is$\int_p^{\infty}e^{-t}dt$ and solve for p which gives me p = 1

Comment: Do you mean that it gives you $p=0$?

Comment: Yes, my bad, ln(1) = 0 I don't know why I assumed it was -1.

Comment: In this question, as far as I can tell, you are asked to give a formula in $p$, an $f(p)$, such that $\int_0^{f(p)} e^{-t} dt = p$.  You already know that $e^{-f(p)} = 1-p$.  Take natural logarithms on both sides and you are effectively done.

Comment: The answer says it is $.693$ if I take the natural logarithm then I only have it in terms of p, not an actual number. That is the confusion I am having.

Comment: That seems to suggest that $p=0.5$.  Maybe that assumption is made  somewhere before the question?

Comment: @FabioSomenzi, I'm unsure I can do links here, so if I can't let me know but here is the link: http://faculty.atu.edu/mfinan/actuarieshall/Pbook.pdf

If you go to page 259 out of 523 in the PDF the question is there and I posted the entire question. If I can't post links let me know and I'll delete it asap.

Comment: If the PDF file is publicly accessible, I see no problem linking to it, but I'm not the authority on the house rules here at SE.  I suspect the author just forgot to add "for $p=1/2$" to the question.